# Proyecto con Navigation Drawer (menu lateral) creado por defecto por Android Studio. Forma de trabajar

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-navigationview

Es la primera vez que trabajo con fragments en Android para una aplicación con Navigation Drawer (menu lateral) escrita en Java que por defecto Android Studio me crea con la siguiente estructura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El fragment home tiene un TextView al que quiero acceder desde la clase Java pertinente para empezar a trabajar para mostrar contenido en la pantalla por defecto de la aplicación, pero nunca he trabajado con este sistema con modelo, vista y fragmento.

**fragment_home.xml**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.home.HomeFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Android Studio me crea un modelo:

**HomeViewModel.java**

```
package com.geologyapplications.minerals.ui.home;

import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData;
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel;

public class HomeViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private MutableLiveData<String> mText;

    public HomeViewModel() {
        mText = new MutableLiveData<>();
        mText.setValue("This is home fragment");
    }

    public LiveData<String> getText() {
        return mText;
    }
}
```

Y una clase HomeFragment.java desde la que entiendo se debe acceder a los elementos del xml del fragment para empezar a mostrar contenido.

Trato de acceder al TextView del archivo xml del fragmento y añadir un texto de prueba. Solo he añadido las dos líneas comentadas a este archivo del proyecto que genera Android Studio:

```
TextView txthome = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.text_home);
txthome.setText("Texto de prueba");
```

**HomeFragment.java**

```
package com.geologyapplications.minerals.ui.home;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;

import com.geologyapplications.minerals.R;
import com.geologyapplications.minerals.databinding.FragmentHomeBinding;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private HomeViewModel homeViewModel;
    private FragmentHomeBinding binding;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        homeViewModel =
            new ViewModelProvider(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);

        binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        View root = binding.getRoot();
        
        TextView txthome = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.text_home); //Únicas dos líneas añadidas al proyecto inicial con Navigation Drawer que crea Android Studio
        txthome.setText("Texto de prueba");
        
        final TextView textView = binding.textHome;
        homeViewModel.getText().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {
                textView.setText(s);
            }
        });
        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        binding = null;
    }
```

Obtengo que el TextView es un objeto nulo:
`Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference`

¿Cuál es la forma correcta de generar el contenido de un fragment del Navigation Drawer en esta estructura de proyecto que me crea Android Studio por defecto?

Comment: No necesitas esto: `TextView txthome = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.text_home);`, al usar DataBinding, obtienes la referencia al `TextView` desde el objeto `FragmentHomeBinding`, como de hecho ya haces aquí: `final TextView textView = binding.textHome;`, aunque de manera errónea, pues debes ponerlo así: **`final TextView textView = binding.text_home;`**

Comment: @A. Cedano y entonces si modifico el layout fragment_home.xml e incluyo  un listview por ejemplo ¿Cómo hago? ¿`final ListView = binding.textListView`?

Comment: Por decirlo con palabras simples, en ese contexto, por medio de `binding` puedes acceder a cualquier elemento del XML ligado al Fragment, con la notación `binding.elIdDelElemento` del `elIdDelElemento` es el ID que tenga el elemento en su propiedad `android:id=` incluso, si incluyes otros layouts, también puedes acceder a ellos, con la notación `binding.elIdDelLayout.elIdDelElemento`

Comment: @A. Cedano ¿Y el modelo no lo toco? ¿Lo elimino?. Hice `textView.setText("Texto de prueba");` pero se sigue mostrando lo que dice HomeViewModel `mText.setValue("This is home fragment");`

Comment: Ya, aunque realmente el tema [Navigation Drawer](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui) no aparece aquí (como problema). Tu problema en concreto aquí es referente a la [Vinculación de Vistas](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) y a algo mucho más amplio, que es el patrón MVVM.

Comment: No entiendo a qué te refieres con *el modelo* ¿? En cuanto a que se muestra `This is home fragment` en tu TextView, eso es lo correcto. Como ya te dije, esto no va de Navigation Drawer, sino de algo  más profundo y más interesante que es el patrón MVVM (lee sobre ello cuando puedas). La función del ViewModel en ese patrón es permitir que el contenido de la UI cambie de una forma transparente, respetando los ciclos de vida, y garantizando que no haya fugas de memoria, etc. Imagina un código donde pides datos asíncronos, a una API remota, a Firebase, etc ...

Comment: ... pues implementar el patrón MVVM te permitirá cambiar el contenido de la UI cuando esos datos sean obtenidos o esos datos cambien, de una forma muy simple, transparente, sin comprometer la UI, los ciclos de vida de los componentes, etc. O, imagina un RecyclerView donde quitas/pones elementos, o se reciben nuevos elementos desde fuentes remotas, pues MVVM te permitirá actualizar ese RecyclerView sin mayores problemas.

Comment: @A. Cedano Yo es que ya tengo el contenido [publicado](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.geologyapplications.minerals&gl=ES) y trabajo en una actualización de la GUI con menu lateral. Entonces si añado un listView al layout fragment, ¿qué debo de hacer? ¿declarar el elemento xml en el HomeFragment y trabajarlo en el HomeViewModel como está hecho para el texto de prueba que muestra la aplicación por defecto del Studio?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141144/discussion-between-a-cedano-and-universal-learner).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gracias a la ayuda de @A. Cedano, he aprendido que esta es una pregunta sobre arquitectura MVVM Android.

Android Studio genera esta estructura de proyecto porque es la manera correcta y limpia de trabajar con datos que modifica el usuario.

No obstante, en el caso de [mi aplicación](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.geologyapplications.minerals&gl=ES), los datos son estáticos, el usuario no los modifica, y provienen de una base de datos alojada en assets.

La forma de acceder al layout del fragment_home.xml y modificar el contenido de la pantalla de inicio sin trabajar con arquitectura MVVM es eliminar la clase HomeViewModel, declarar el item xml en la clase HomeFragment.java y modificar su contenido.

**HomeFragment.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import com.geologyapplications.minerals.databinding.FragmentHomeBinding;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {


    private FragmentHomeBinding binding;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        View root = binding.getRoot();
    
        final TextView textView = binding.textHome;
        textView.setText("Texto de prueba");
        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        binding = null;
    }
}
```

Y el texto de prueba se muestra en la pantalla por defecto del Navigation Drawer.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ten en cuenta que cuando implementas el Componente de Navegación combinado con Navigation Drawer, los destinos se definen en un XML que está dentro de la carpeta `navigation`. Es ahí dónde se indica a qué Fragment irá cada destino y qué layout deberá cargar. Por eso, usando Componente de Navegación puedes tener una App con una sola Activity y usar Fragment para todo lo demás, que es lo que hace precisamente el código de ejemplo que te carga Android por defecto.